# Does Amazon Gamecircle expose player's email address?

Tags: amazon-gamecircle

Does anyone knows if Amazon GameCircle exposes a player's email address to the app? According to [this documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/binaries/content/assets/javadoc/gamecircle-api/2_4/reference/com/amazon/ags/api/player/player.html), the API only exposes player's Alias (probably the nickname chosen by player), Avatar URL, and PlayerID (which is a unique string identifying the player). So is it safe to say that an app/game developer cannot fetch player's Amazon account's email address via GameCircle?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, if their docs say so...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Their documentation don't say anything explicitly about email address.